# Router TP-Link blocking IP address when I upload file on html form

Tags: javascript, php, router, firewall

I don't have any idea where is a problem. I have a router TP-link TL-WR940N and this device blocking my computer (firewall blocking IP Address) when I upload image by html form. I thought the problem are a big POST request. I modifing this code to AJAX upload file. Now i send files one by one - I send first file, waiting to complete and sending next file. My TP-Link are still blocking IP. I find 3 options in router config which genrate problem:

ICMP-FLOOD Attack Filtering

UDP-FLOOD Filtering

TCP-SYN-FLOOD Attack Filtering

Has anyone had this problem?

My actual js code:

```
  function uploadFileAsync(idProduct, alt, iteration, files) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    var arrFilesLength = files.length;
    var file = files[iteration]; 

    formData.delete('fileGal[]');
    formData.set('fileGal[]', file, file.name);

    $.ajax({        
      url: documentDomain + 'admin.php?uploadFile=' + idProduct + '&imgAlt=' + alt,
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,

      data: formData,

      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,

      success: function(data) {
        iteration++;

        if (iteration == arrFilesLength) {
          $('progress').css('display', 'none');
          $('.fileGal').val('');
          $('.imurConvertGood').hide();
          $('.productGalleryTitle').html('No file');
          refreshPicturesList(idProduct);
        } else {
          $('progress').attr({
            value: iteration,
            max: arrFilesLength,
          });

          uploadFileAsync(idProduct, alt, iteration, files);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Upload PHP:

```
private function uploadFile($idProduct = null, $fi = null, $imgAlt = null) {
  $config = new Config;

  $idProduct = htmlspecialchars($idProduct, ENT_QUOTES);
  $fi = htmlspecialchars($fi, ENT_QUOTES);

  $pathFilesServer = $this->AppModel->pathFilesServer();

  $productSQL = $this->AppModel->selectData('products', array('name', 'aliasID'), array('id' => $idProduct));
  $productArr = $productSQL->fetch_assoc();

  $aliasNameSQL = $this->AppModel->selectData('alias', 'alias', array('id' => $productArr['aliasID']));
  $aliasName = $aliasNameSQL->fetch_assoc();  

  if (is_array($_FILES['fileGal']['name'])) {
    if ($fi == null) $fi=0;
    $fc = count($_FILES['fileGal']['name']);
    $file_name = $_FILES['fileGal']['name'][$fi];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileGal']['tmp_name'][$fi];
    $fi++;
  } else {
    $file_name = $_FILES['fileGal']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileGal']['tmp_name'];
  }

  $file_name = strtolower($file_name);


  /* new name file */
  $today = getdate();
  $md=md5($today[0]+rand());

  $tmp = explode(".", $file_name);
  $extension = end($tmp);

  if ($aliasName['alias'] != '') {
    $newName = $aliasName['alias'].'-'.rand(1000, 9999).'.'.$extension;
  } else {
    $newName = $md.'.'.$extension;
  }


  $path = $pathFilesServer.'/Store/imgProducts/orginal/'.$newName;

  $fileFromImagick = $this->helpers->resizeImage($file_tmp, 250, 250, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, true, null);
  file_put_contents ($pathFilesServer.'/Store/imgProducts/min/'.$newName, $fileFromImagick);

  $fileFromImagick = $this->helpers->resizeImage($file_tmp, 500, 500, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, true, null);
  file_put_contents ($pathFilesServer.'/Store/imgProducts/middle/'.$newName, $fileFromImagick);

  /* start upload file */
  if(is_uploaded_file($file_tmp)) { 
   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path); 
  }

 if ($imgAlt == null) {
   $this->AppModel->insertValue('pictures', array('id' => '', 'idProduct' => $idProduct, 'file' => $newName, 'alt' => $productArr['name']));
 } else {
   $this->AppModel->insertValue('pictures', array('id' => '', 'idProduct' => $idProduct, 'file' => $newName, 'alt' => $imgAlt));
 }

 if ($fi<$fc){
  $this->uploadFile($idProduct, $fi);
 } else {}
}
```

Comment: I doubt your router is doing that. Perhaps something else is going on

Comment: Why do you think its the router fault?

Comment: @Marc I think its the router fault becouse my local IP address are on black list. When I clear black list all working good

Comment: If it's your router, it's not a programming question.

Comment: @jabaa I'm asking if anyone has had a similar problem from the programming side. Maybe there is a problem with my code and it is perceived by the router as an attack?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with your code. What's your actual question? Do you want to change your code to avoid this behavior?.in that case you should either ask TP-Link support or read the router docs to find out, what you have to do.

Comment: @jabaa Thanks for confirming that my code is good. Will contact tp-link